# error of foreach with empty array

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm working in Laravel 5 using Blade as motor of templates. I'm passing an array from the controller to the view, and I noticed that when I loop on it using the *foreach* clausule and the array is empty it gives error, exactly this:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I had the same error in the controller and I fix it temporaly making:

```
if(count($student)!=0)
```

I said *temporaly* because I don't think it this the best way to do it.
The code in the controller is:

```
foreach($students as $student){
        if(count($student->contracts)!=0)
            foreach($student->contracts as $contract){
                 //something
            }//end foreach
    }//end foreach
```

I made some operations over the arrays, and then I send them to the view:

```
return view('myview')->with(['students'=>$students]);
```

The array is passing to the view correctly. I said is the foreach, beacause earlier I had the database full of registers and it worked fine, but now I have some students that doesn't have contracts and then I got that error. But, in the view I have the same error. So, it's normal? how could I fix it in a better way? why when the array is empty the *foreach* clausule gives that error?

Comment: What is the value of `$student`?

Comment: is an object of the 'Model' User, I checked it and are 2 students exactly, when I put the if statement that gives no error. The thing is that $student is an array, and inside him I have another array of $contracts

Comment: It cannot be both a `User` object and an array at the same time. Is it an array containing two `User` objects, or something else?

Comment: I edited the post, I added some code @BenM and yes, is an array of the object Users, they are the result of a query to the database

Answer (score 2):

PHP will not return that warning if the array contained at `$student->contracts` is empty. It will return it if it is of an invalid type (i.e. not an array).

Rather than checking the `count()` of `$student->contracts`, you'd be better to check if it's actually an array, as follows:

```
foreach($students as $student)
{
    // Make sure that $student->contracts is actually an array (to bypass errors):
    if( is_array($student->contracts) )
    {
        // Now loop through it:
        foreach( $student->contracts as $contract)
        {
            // Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man! that worked pretty well. But I still had to put an if statement in the view. I think that is a thing with no choice. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$people = [
        "Person A", "Person B", "Person C"
];
return view ('pages', compact('people'));
```

and loop through it like this:

```
@if (count($people))
    <h3>People:</h3>
    <ul>
        @foreach($people as $person)
            <li>{{ $person }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: sure, I made that too!! Thanks ;)

Comment: Usage of supressors (`@`) isn't really good ways of handling things. That first `if`-statement would never throw an error, and if you always check that the count is larger than 0, there would be no errors in the `foreach`-loop either.